# retrieve only the data from the rows those are not empty

Tags: mysql

suppose I have 2 columns username and password and I want to retrieve only the data from the rows those are not empty. how to do it in php or mysql? Plz provide solution in both php and mysql.

*from the comments*

I tried this `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND username != " "` and it works only for one column. What if I have to check empty fields for multiple columns?

Comment: You have users without either a username or a password?

Comment: Every row should be filled right? Cause it's USERNAME AND PASSWORD?

Comment: I tied this SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND username != " " and it works only for one column, what if i have to check empty fields for multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if((!name.eual(""))and(!password.equal("")){
    // code here
}
```

Comment: ... Aren't you missing an )?

Comment: This is the complete code where i've to add ur code ? require_once('config.php');
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND username != '' ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['username'] . "=" ;
echo $row['password'];
echo "<br>";
}

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, password FROM table_name WHERE table_name.username!='' AND table_name.password!='';
```

In case you do select everything even the blank rows. with `SELECT * FROM table_name`

In your php assuming that $data is the output of your query do a loop like this

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
   if(($key == 'username' && $value == '') || ($key == 'password' && $value == '')){
      // row with blank username and password.
   }
}
```

Comment: No problem, take care.

Comment: @Jamie Seriously though. Username and password... How can 1 be empty?

Comment: loko its just a task given to us. i'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND password IS NOT NULL"